# check if div contains li then removing another element using jquery

Tags: jquery

If `div#FeatureIconsWrapper` contains NO `li`

Then `div#productInfoGrid` is hidden by either by css or removed completly.

I have tried(is this correct?):

```
$("div#FeatureIconsWrapper:not(li)")({
    $("div#productInfoGrid").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
if (!$("#FeatureIconsWrapper:has(li)").length) {
    $("#productInfoGrid").hide();   // or remove()
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8T4ka/2/

Comment: whats the opposite of `:HAS`  ??

Comment: @Matt I thought about that but finally moved to simple `length` check. It might be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8T4ka/1/)**

```
if($("div#FeatureIconsWrapper li").length == 0)
{
    $("div#FeatureIconsWrapper").hide();
}
```

Comment: `this` won't be anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

API: http://api.jquery.com/has/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       if ($("div#FeatureIconsWrappet:not(:has(li))")) { //.hide()
               $("div#productInfoGrid").hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: Wow, never knew about `has()`